# Mac Mavericks Java unable to locate executable bash_profile edits have not worked

Tags: java, macos, terminal

When I enter

```
java -version
```

it returns

`Unable to locate an executable at "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework//bin/java" (-1)`

If I enter

```
which java
```

it returns

```
/usr/bin/java
```

I have looked online and found very similar problems but the general solution of editing the bash_profile and adding the code below does not work

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
```

Any help on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java in /usr/bin is just a symbolic link to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework//bin/java.  This is standard on MacOS.  It sounds like target of the symlink does not exist.  You can fix this in one of two ways.

1. Install a new version of Java.  The installer should properly set the symlink.
2. Manually set the symlink to a valid version of Java already installed in your system.  If any exist, you will find them under /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions.

To manually update the symlink, you will need admin privileges.  Thus if the commands below do not work, try running them via sudo (i.e. put sudo in front of each command).  Note the commands below assume you have java 1.6 installed.  You will have to search your system to see exactly what versions are there an use the appropriate path the the java executable.

```
   cd /usr/bin
   rm java
   ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Commands/java
```

Comment: Thanks I tried installing a new version earlier but this had no effect. I tried option 2 and if I LL that folder I get:
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   59 11 Dec 09:31 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents. How do I manually set the symlink, I don't know how to do that part?

Comment: Hey mate thanks but that still didn't work. I have no idea how my Java got so messed up :(

Comment: Did you upgrade to Mavericks recently by any chance?  When I did so, I ran into trouble as the upgrade altered my installed version of java.

Comment: Yes I did I thought that was the problem! How did you solve it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43072/discussion-between-ejk-and-clinton-green)